# Call a method from one class from within another class

Tags: java, rjava

I am trying to call the method from one class using a method within a second class (which should return a list), however, the second class method is not being recognised. I don't receive any visible errors or warnings.

My first class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class testClass {

        public static List<Object> makeStuff() {

            int a = 2;
            double b = 3.1;             
            return Arrays.asList(a, b);         
        }
    }
```

And the second

```
import java.util.*;

public class otherClass {

    public List<Object> outputStuff() {

        // create some other stuff here which will be appended to id
        List<Object> id = testClass.makeStuff();
        return id ;
    }

    public void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

From [How to access a method from a class from another class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39175922/how-to-access-a-method-from-a-class-from-another-class) I thought this would work as the first method is static. Where am I making the mistake please?

---

---

Extra info if required: I am actually interfacing this code with R using `rJava`, but receive an error indicating that the `java` is wrong.

This returns the values as expected for the first class/method

```
library(rJava)
.jinit()
.jaddClassPath("C:\\Users\\david\\eclipse-workspace\\SOtest\\bin")    
myJavaClass <- .jnew("testClass")
x <- J(myJavaClass, "makeStuff")
x
# [1] "Java-Object{[2, 3.1]}"
```

but not for the second

```
.jinit()
.jaddClassPath("C:\\Users\\david\\eclipse-workspace\\SOtest\\bin")    
myJavaClass <- .jnew("otherClass")
x <- J(myJavaClass, "outputStuff")
```

throws the error

> Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
>     java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: otherClass.outputStuff()

Comment: It's because `outputStuff` is not static.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @KlitosKyriacou. So I should update to `public static List<Object> outputStuff()`, and/or `public static void main` ?

Comment: You only need `public static void main` if you want to execute your application from Java. You don't need to define main at all if you want to call a Java class from R.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with the code. Main method should be

```
public static void main(String a[]){ new otherClass().otherstuff();}
```

That should be enough. We can call static methods from non-static methods by Class name.

So to call otherstuff from main either make otherstuff as static or create new instance of otherClass and call directly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there any benefit in applying `static` to both the `outputStuff()` method and the `main` call or is it okay just on the `main`? Re your edit; the code seemed to run (no errors in java or R) without the additional `new otherClass().otherstuff();`

Comment: _Nothing wrong with the code._ **but** change all these things. How does this explain the error message they get from rjava?

Answer (score 0):

You can make your `outputStuff` static and it should work, as that one is the method you are trying to invoque

Answer (score -1):

Main method should be public static void main(String[] args). 
Calling static method from non static method is perfectly fine.