# How to access methods inside another classes through instance of another class in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two classes as follows.

```
class Users{
    createUser(){
       //...
    }
}
```

Another class

```
class Cars{
    createCar(){
       //....
    }
}
```

Main class

```
class Api{
    //....
}
```

I need to access the first two classes though last class as follows

```
Api=new API()
Api.Users.createUser()
//also
Api.Cars.createCar()
```

How it is possible in javascript. is this a good practice?

Comment: Use dependency injection, `class Api { constructor(users, cars) { this.users = users, this.cars = cars } }` and `Api = new Api(new User, new Car)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39175922/how-to-access-a-method-from-a-class-from-another-class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
class Users {
    createUser(){
       console.log('createUser');
    }
}

class Cars {
    createCar(){
       console.log('createCar')
    }
}

class Api  {
    Users = new Users;
    Cars = new Cars;
}

var api = new Api()
api.Users.createUser()
api.Cars.createCar()
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create an instance of each class inside the API class. Then you can access them through dot notation and call their respective public functions.