# (Express, Node, TypeScript, REST API) How can I import a function from the service to the controllers? Property ... does not exist on type typeof

Tags: node.js, typescript, rest, express, authentication

How should I import loginMember in Controller? I am developing a REST API and now I need to use code in a different file location. I am having an error in the controller. When I am calling loginMember. (Cannot find name 'loginMember'.ts(2304))

**SERVICE**

```
import MembersModel from '../models/MembersModel';
import BaseService from './BaseService';
import { createPasswordToHash } from '../scripts/utils/auth';
class MembersService extends BaseService {  
  constructor() {
    super(MembersModel);
  }

  // loginMember
  loginMember = async (email: any, password: any) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        let data = await this.BaseModel.findOne({
          email: email,
          password: createPasswordToHash(password),
        });
        return resolve(data);
      } catch (error) {
        return reject(error);
      }
    });
  };
  
}

export default MembersService;
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
import BaseController from './BaseController';
import MembersService from '../services/MembersService';
import ApiError from '../errors/ApiError';
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';
import { createPasswordToHash, generateAccessToken } from '../scripts/utils/auth';
import httpStatus from 'http-status';

class MembersController extends BaseController {
  constructor(membersService: MembersService) {
    super(membersService);    
  }

login = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  MembersService.loginMember(req.body)
    .then((response: any) => {
      if (response) {
        const member = {
          ...response.toObject(),
          accessToken: generateAccessToken(response.toObject()),
        };
        delete member.password;
        delete member.createdAt;
        delete member.updatedAt;
        return res.status(httpStatus.OK).send(member);
      }
      return res.status(httpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).send({ error: 'Invalid email or password' });
    })
    .catch((err: { message: string }) => {
      return next(
        new ApiError(err.message, httpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, 'login', req.headers['user-agent']?.toString() || 'Unknown')
      );
    });
};
  
}
export default new MembersController(new MembersService());
```

Now I am gettig a new error: **"Property 'loginMember' does not exist on type 'typeof MembersService'.ts(2339)"**

Comment: This question has some answers already - if you search for "use class method in another class javascript" in google you'll see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39175922/how-to-access-a-method-from-a-class-from-another-class That should answer your question, lmk if you still need help

Comment: But i am calling from another file.

Comment: @Zevgon i am trying `MembersService.loginMember(req.body)` but error says Property 'loginMember' does not exist on type 'typeof MembersService'.ts(2339)

Comment: that's because the method is not static in MemberService. There are a few ways you can fix this:

1. Define the `loginMember` method as static by replacing `loginMember` with `static loginMember` in MemberService.
2. Create a new instance of MemberService in MembersController by replacing `MembersService.loginMember` with `new MembersService().loginMember`.
3. Add `this.memberService = memberService` in the constructor and then call `this.memberService.loginMember`

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static for info about static methods

Comment: sorry, I didn't notice that the keyword `this` is used in the `loginMember` method. That means that the 2nd and 3rd options in my previous comment are the only ones that will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to call `loginMember` as a [static method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static), but it's not defined as one. You'll have to use an instance of `MembersService` to use the method. Since your `MembersController` is already being initialized with a `MembersService` instance, you may just want to have a `membersService` property on the `MembersController`. Also, the `loginMember` method takes an email and a password, so you'll have to pass those arguments explicitly instead of just passing the request body. (I'm not sure where the email and password are in the request body though, so I can't help you there.) So with those changes, it would look like:

```
class MembersController extends BaseController {
  private membersService: MembersService;

  constructor(membersService: MembersService) {
    super(membersService);
    this.membersService = membersService;
  }

login = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  this.membersService.loginMember(email, password) // <- Get these from the request
    .then((response: any) => {
      if (response) {
        const member = {
          ...response.toObject(),
          accessToken: generateAccessToken(response.toObject()),
        };
        delete member.password;
        delete member.createdAt;
        delete member.updatedAt;
        return res.status(httpStatus.OK).send(member);
      }
      return res.status(httpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).send({ error: 'Invalid email or password' });
    })
    .catch((err: { message: string }) => {
      return next(
        new ApiError(err.message, httpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, 'login', req.headers['user-agent']?.toString() || 'Unknown')
      );
    });
};
```

One other code style suggestion would be to use `async` `await` instead of `.then` in the `login` method. Also, the Promise wrapping in the `loginMember` method looks unnecessary, and using an async function as the argument is an [antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43036229/is-it-an-anti-pattern-to-use-async-await-inside-of-a-new-promise-constructor). The following should get the job done while avoiding those pitfalls:

```
  loginMember = (email: any, password: any): Promise<Response> => {
    return this.BaseModel.findOne({
      email: email,
      password: createPasswordToHash(password),
    });
  };
```

Comment: Thank u so much @Zevgon. Everything seems fine. But when I try to login, I get 'Invalid email or password' warning even if the mail and password are correct.

Comment: ``.loginMember(req)``  is the **req** here wrong code?

Comment: Yes, `.loginMember(req)` will fail because the `loginMember` function is expecting an email and a password, not a request object. So you'll have to find the email and password in the request, and then pass them as 2 separate arguments: `.loginMember(email, password)`

Comment: i edit loginMember like this ``.loginMember( { email: req.body.email, password: req.body.password } )``, i am getting 'Invalid email or password' again. Should i change ``.then((response: any) => ...)`` to ``.then((email: res.body.email, password: res.body.password) => ...)``

Comment: Ah ok, there was an error in the if construction.

Comment: You're still passing a single argument into the `loginMember` method, which won't work. `{ email: req.body.email, password: req.body.password }` is a single object, and that's what you're using as the argument. You have to provide 2 arguments that are not wrapped inside an object, so like this: `.loginMember(req.body.email, req.body.password)`

Comment: I won't be able to help with any more debugging of this unfortunately, since we've already drifted away from the main purpose of StackOverflow, which is individual questions and answers rather than debugging several items at once. Most of these individual issues should have answers elsewhere in StackOverflow, although I know it can be hard to know what to look for when you're just starting out.... I'd probably suggest a tutor, or a JavaScript tutorial like CodeCademy to get familiar with these concepts of arguments, promises, objects, class methods, etc.